# Google search results change links colors

Tags: search, google-search-console

I'm getting crazy to change the colours in the custom google search we have implemented at work... been researching for a few hours and nothing...

we are using this:

```
<div id="search">
    <div id="results_007269481408127051346:b2b1fyxrklw"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var googleSearchIframeName = "results_007269481408127051346:b2b1fyxrklw";
    var googleSearchFormName = "searchbox_007269481408127051346:b2b1fyxrklw";
    var googleSearchFrameWidth = 600;    
    var googleSearchFrameborder = 0;
    var googleSearchDomain = "www.google.com";
    var googleSearchPath = "/cse";
    var googleSearchResizeIframe = true;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://www.google.com/afsonline/show_afs_search.js"></script>
```

Do you know if theres any other var that I can add to these parameters to change the blue and the green color  that come by default in the search?

Thanks a lot folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go to Google Webmaster Tools and then to Labs > Custom Search you can configure a new search engine. There are 4 tabs, in the second tab Look and Feel you can customize its appearance.

This style-sheet should be generated and putting this in your style-sheet should edit its appearance :)

```
<style type="text/css">
  .gsc-control-cse {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-color: #FF0000;
    background-color: #999999;
  }
  .gsc-control-cse .gsc-table-result {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  }
  input.gsc-input {
    border-color: #FFFFCC;
  }
  input.gsc-search-button {
    border-color: #999999;
    background-color: #FFCC00;
  }
  .gsc-tabHeader.gsc-tabhInactive {
    border-color: #E9E9E9;
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
  }
  .gsc-tabHeader.gsc-tabhActive {
    border-top-color: #FF9900;
    border-left-color: #E9E9E9;
    border-right-color: #E9E9E9;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .gsc-tabsArea {
    border-color: #E9E9E9;
  }
  .gsc-webResult.gsc-result,
  .gsc-results .gsc-imageResult {
    border-color: #000000;
    background-color: #660000;
  }
  .gsc-webResult.gsc-result:hover,
  .gsc-imageResult:hover {
    border-color: #009900;
    background-color: #CC33CC;
  }
  .gsc-webResult.gsc-result.gsc-promotion:hover {
    border-color: #009900;
    background-color: #CC33CC;
  }
  .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:link,
  .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:link b,
  .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:link,
  .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:link b {
    color: #666666;
  }
  .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:visited,
  .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:visited b,
  .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:visited,
  .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:visited b {
    color: #C0C0C0;
  }
  .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:hover,
  .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:hover b,
  .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:hover,
  .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:hover b {
    color: #999999;
  }
  .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:active,
  .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:active b,
  .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:active,
  .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:active b {
    color: #666666;
  }
  .gsc-cursor-page {
    color: #666666;
  }
  a.gsc-trailing-more-results:link {
    color: #666666;
  }
  .gs-webResult .gs-snippet,
  .gs-imageResult .gs-snippet,
  .gs-fileFormatType {
    color: #CCCCCC;
  }
  .gs-webResult div.gs-visibleUrl,
  .gs-imageResult div.gs-visibleUrl {
    color: #330000;
  }
  .gs-webResult div.gs-visibleUrl-short {
    color: #330000;
  }
  .gs-webResult div.gs-visibleUrl-short {
    display: none;
  }
  .gs-webResult div.gs-visibleUrl-long {
    display: block;
  }
  .gs-promotion div.gs-visibleUrl-short {
    display: none;
  }
  .gs-promotion div.gs-visibleUrl-long {
    display: block;
  }
  .gsc-cursor-box {
    border-color: #000000;
  }
  .gsc-results .gsc-cursor-box .gsc-cursor-page {
    border-color: #E9E9E9;
    background-color: #660000;
    color: #666666;
  }
  .gsc-results .gsc-cursor-box .gsc-cursor-current-page {
    border-color: #FF9900;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #C0C0C0;
  }
  .gsc-webResult.gsc-result.gsc-promotion {
    border-color: #336699;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .gsc-completion-title {
    color: #666666;
  }
  .gsc-completion-snippet {
    color: #CCCCCC;
  }
  .gs-promotion a.gs-title:link,
  .gs-promotion a.gs-title:link *,
  .gs-promotion .gs-snippet a:link {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gs-promotion a.gs-title:visited,
  .gs-promotion a.gs-title:visited *,
  .gs-promotion .gs-snippet a:visited {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gs-promotion a.gs-title:hover,
  .gs-promotion a.gs-title:hover *,
  .gs-promotion .gs-snippet a:hover {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gs-promotion a.gs-title:active,
  .gs-promotion a.gs-title:active *,
  .gs-promotion .gs-snippet a:active {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gs-promotion .gs-snippet,
  .gs-promotion .gs-title .gs-promotion-title-right,
  .gs-promotion .gs-title .gs-promotion-title-right *  {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .gs-promotion .gs-visibleUrl,
  .gs-promotion .gs-visibleUrl-short {
    color: #008000;
  }</style>
```